# Слетела кодировка UTF-8 на Open Server, что делать?

Tags: mysql, кодировка, utf-8, openserver, charset

У меня слетела кодировка `UTF-8` на Локальном сервере `Open Server`.

Что самое интересное, слетела только часть, а другие текста поддерживают русский язык.

Вот скриншот [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить эту проблему? При переносе этого файла `header.php` на хостинг клиента, возможно ли такое, что кодировка слетит также, как у меня на локальном сервере?

Comment: Важно знать, есть ли взаимодействие с базой данных. И да есть вероятность потери времени во время деплоя из за несоответствия конфигураций, поэтому опытные программисты использую Vagrant и Docker